Tags firing on Preview mode but not in live. Works on Safari only
I’m facing an issue where I published an HTML GTM tag, and when I test it in preview mode, the tag triggered by the Purchase event fires correctly. However, when I test it 'live' on Google Chrome or Edge, this tag doesn’t fire. The trigger event 'purchase' is activated, but the tag itself does not fire. When I perform the same test in the Safari browser, the tag fires normally. I’m not sure what the issue could be. The cookies involved in firing the tags are all set to SameSite=None and Secure.
I hope to understand the reason why it fires in one browser and in preview mode, but not in Chrome.
